# Sharepoint rest api Filter not working on response

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to fetch data from rest api using filter but somehow it's not working.

I am trying below different combinations like below rest endpoints:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SectionE')/items?items?$select=Id&filter=Title eq 'Test'

/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SectionE')/items?items?$select=Id&filter=Title%20eq%20%27Test%27
```

I want results to be filtered based on the value in the Title column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle("SectionE")/items?$select=ID,Title&$filter=Title eq 'Test'
```

Comment: I didn't included $ before filter and it works after putting $filter

Answer (score 0):

For filter a field value in Rest API, here is a common example:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$select=columnname&filter=columnname eq 'somevalue'
```

You can check in browser to see the data returned:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SectionE')/items?items?$select=Id&$filter=Title eq 'Test'

$ before filter was missing.